# EntityManager remove throws Object: null is not a known entity type

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I am trying to delete a record in the database using EntityManager. I am using EJB JPA.

It produces the error : `Object: null is not a known entity type`.

Here is my code:

```
public void deleteAppointment(int staffID, int appointmentID) {
    try {

        StaffApointmentsPK staffApointmentsPK = new StaffApointmentsPK();
        staffApointmentsPK.setAppointmentId(appointmentID);
        staffApointmentsPK.setStaffId(staffID);

        StaffApointments staffApointments = staffApointmentsFacade.find(staffApointmentsPK);

        System.out.println("staff app type " + staffApointments);

        em.remove(staffApointments);
        em.flush();
```

But in my early call to the function below, it is very similar but it is working. I do not understand what is the problem because I am searching for the entity first using `staffApointmentsFacade`.

Here is my other function which works:

```
public StaffApointments getPatientAppointmentDetails(int appointmentID, int staffID) {

        StaffApointmentsPK staffApointmentsPK = new StaffApointmentsPK();
        staffApointmentsPK.setAppointmentId(appointmentID);
        staffApointmentsPK.setStaffId(staffID);
        StaffApointments staffApointments = staffApointmentsFacade.find(staffApointmentsPK);

return staffApointments;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

I solved it by switching the `int staffID, int appointmentID` respectively. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What is th output of `System.out.println("staff app type " + staffApointments);`? It looks like staffApointments is null...

Comment: @Puce Yes. It outputs staffApointments is nulll. I do not how why it outputs null because "getPatientAppointmentDetails" works when i try to output System.out.println("staff app type " + staffApointments)

Comment: Are you really sure you call the `deleteAppointment` function correctly? I noticed that the supplied id's are mixed up in the method signature when comparing it to `getPatientAppointmentDetails`.

Comment: @ma-ver-ick Yes. I am calling the deleteAppointment correctly, because If i wasnt able to call it it correctly, it would not output System.out.println("staff app type " + staffApointments) which is null

Comment: @MLDS I think what @ma-ver-ick is asking is that the signature of `deleteAppointment` is `deleteAppointment(int staffID, int appointmentID)` but the signature of `getPatientAppointmentDetails` is `getPatientAppointmentDetails(int appointmentID, int staffID)`. Note how `int appointmentID` and `int staffID` are swapped around in one of these methods. So when you call `deleteAppointment` are you sure you are passing `appointmentID` and `staffID` in the correct order and not maybe passing `appointmentID` as `staffID` and vice versa by mistake?

Comment: @DonovanMuller Sorry for not understanding the question clearly. Looks like that was the mistake that I made. Such a minor mistake. Sorry. My bad! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MLDS Can you add the code for `staffApointmentsFacade.find(staffApointmentsPK)`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching the int staffID, int appointmentID respectively. Thanks for all your help @Donovan and @ma-ve-rick